# my dvd has shown as raw format but used some spaces

Tags: partitioning, dvd, udf, raw

my friend has a DVD contains some larg images,but windows doesn't show any thing inside.
windows disk partition utility tells its format type is RAW.
in MyComputer , everything is fine, it means that shows the DVD Driver with used space and the disk volume. but when i open it , i see a blank disk.

a weird thing i'v never seen is the Burning side of disk , there are two circle burning line with a space between. is it a sign of crashed dvd? or it is an encrypted dvd ? or ..?

what can i do to read data?

> a note that i should say is i tested UDF format in ubuntu , but ubuntu
>   told this:
>   [  560.261756] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_tagged: read failed, block=128, location=128
>   [  575.346465] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
>   [  575.346473] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
>   [  575.346478] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
>   [  575.346484] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 01 01 00 00 01 00
>   [  575.346489] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1028
>   [  575.346732] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_tagged: read failed, block=257, location=0
>   [  575.346738] UDF-fs: warning (device sr0): udf_fill_super: No fileset found
>   [  588.742146] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s3 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:23:b1:79:59:55:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
>   [  590.292298] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s3 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fc:14:2d:27:21:53:4b:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.23 DST=224.0.0.252 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=28305 PROTO=2

thank you in advance

**update**

Thank you [Tiago_nes](https://superuser.com/users/494844/tiago-nes)

I was used the isobuster but I've not waited till completed . I have tried again and has found some images. The dvd were crashed on burning and has unreadable sectors.

Comment: Verify that the DVD is good, read it and compare the data with the original files (on your friend's computer?). Maybe it's just a coaster

Comment: The problem is i can't read the data and this dvd is the only one.

Comment: If your friend (the creator) can't read the dvd either, especially on the same drive that created it, then it sounds like a failed write, and it's a coaster/Frisbee, etc. If you think there's actual data on it and it's readable, you could try data recovery / file carving

Comment: My friend has received this DVD from a third party that has insisted the DVD is healthy and working.But now, when I test on any system (though I have not yet tested on a Mac), I'm not able to read the data.Now it's not possible to find out if the information in the source system is readable.

Comment: Hmm... try reading it in Linux, and on a few different drives/computers. Maybe your friend just got ripped off.

Comment: I have tried. In ubuntu. in question i write the ubuntu answer on mounting the dvd rom(sr0). You mean read the dvd for example dvd player device,...?

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this here because i can't comment yet.
I wont answer to your question but here is something that can help you.
There is some special ways to burn a dvd that leaves blank spaces between the burns like the PS2 Dvd "Swap Magic" here is an

> https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/7BgAAOSwdvtZqTLn/s-l225.jpg

Comment: Thanks. Yes it is similar. My dvd have two burn lines.

Comment: The one who burned the Dvd may have triggered some special way for burning the dvd that way...
Where does the Dvd come from?
Who burned it?

Comment: Is there a chance some 1 activated some special option for burning the dvd like that?

Comment: A photographer take some pictures and burns it.i dont know how he is doing this!!

Comment: I recomend you get in touch with him and check why is the disk like that...

Comment: Unfortunately, we do not have access to the photographer. I can only test all probabilities to read the data.

Comment: Then  can only recomend you a tool to try recovering disk content.

Comment: [Here](https://www.powerdatarecovery.com/cd-dvd-recovery.html) is a pretty decent 1

Comment: I have check this software. But doesnt recognize the dvd. But i will test it again.thanks.